# Как сделать поля checkout в мини-корзине

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я сделал мини-корзину.
Но как в нее добавить поля чекаута?

Добавлял форму прямиком из файла checkout.php, но не сработало

Пример на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]